# Unity: Find out, if user has clicked on an ad

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

In my unity app I integrated Admob.
This is the code in my "Ads" class:

```
public static InterstitialAd interstitial;


private void Start()
{
    RequestInterstitial();
}

public void StartAds()
{
    RequestInterstitial();

    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Interstitial wasn't loaded yet");
    }

    interstitial.Show(); 
}

public static void onAdLeftApplication()
{
    ChangeCoinValue.actualCoinValue += 33;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TotalCoinValue", ChangeCoinValue.actualCoinValue);
}


private void RequestInterstitial()
{

    // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    // Create an empty ad request.
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    // Load the interstitial with the request.
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
}
```

Ads do show just perfeclty when I am in another class and call (upon a button click for instance:)

```
Ads.Interstitial.Show();
```

I'm doing it this way, because in mono develope you cannot work with objects so it needs to be static. But nevertheless:

So I have thought that the function in my ad class "OnAdLeftApplication()"
fires every time the user clicks on an ad and therfore leaves the application. If he or she were to do this, I would reward this person with 33 coins!

But it doesnt work. Maybe not because I am just calling the "show()" function from my interstitial ad but I dont know.

Can you explain to me, how I get to reward a user with coins when he or she clicks on one of the ads?

Thansk!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `admobEventHandler` for the specific event types `onAdOpened` and `onAdLeftApplication` check the [github wiki page](https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob/wiki/Admob-Unity-Plugin-API) for more event types.

Before you call `interstitial.LoadAd`you have to subscribe the interstial to that event. Something like `interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;`

```
public void HandleInterstitialLeftApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Comment: thanks. I did read that and thats why I am using my function: public static void onAdLeftApplication()
{
    ChangeCoinValue.actualCoinValue += 33;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TotalCoinValue", ChangeCoinValue.actualCoinValue);
} but it doenst fire when the ad is clicked.

Comment: you have to subscribe the event to the interstitial to the event before you call loadad. i'll edit my answer

Comment: FANTASTIC! This was what was missing :)

Comment: Topper! Thats exactly what I needed.